# jQuery getJSON error: Refused to execute script l because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable

Tags: executable, getjson

I am trying to get my IP camera image on my web application using getJSON:

```
myurl = ipcameraurl/jpeg.cgi?jsoncallback=?;

$.getJSON(myurl, {tagmode: "any", format: "json", cache: "false", datatype: "jsonp"}).done( function{}). fail( function{});
```

I tried it on http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne and it works.
But with my IP camera I am getting the error above.
I tried to set contentType: "application/javascript" or "application/json" but this did not fix the problem.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: is this jpeg.cgi something you have control over? You'd have to mod that to output the proper mime content-type, as the error message says.

Comment: No. It is a jpeg image on the IP camera web page. I cannot modify it content-type

Comment: then you can't use .getjson, because it expects **JSON** as the returned data type.  you're telling your browser "go fetch a chocolate bar" from the camera, and the camera's outputting a bowling ball - therefore your browser is correctly saying "not a chocolate bar". and if the camera's cgi script doesn't support jsonp, you can't fetch anything from it in the first place - jsonp REQUIRES the assistance of the remote server, which your camera isn't doing.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the contentType on the $.getJSON to the correct type or the target url service.

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne is XML
add ?format=json in the end to get json.

Comment: If I add ?format=json at the end, I am getting the error below: XMLHttpRequest cannot load  myurl No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:20400' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.   Now the question I asked in my original question is what is the correct contentType to use? Because I tried many and none is working.

Comment: You can use to make the JSONP request http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&callback=?

Comment: I checked the link. I have no idea how it works and how I can use it to solve my problem. Can you give some explanations how to use it?